# Is my email for resume professional enough?

Tags: resume, email, applications

I'm going to apply to a job tomorrow, my email will be forstufff@email.com since this is my main/work email that I use often. I think it's okay, but some of you may think it's a little immature/unprofessional. Any opinions?

Comment: 'forstufff' looks like a typo. Why are there three f's at the end? It would be better if the e-mail username corresponds somehow to your real name (abbreviation or using initials is fine).

Answer (score 0):

Whether an email is appropriate depends entirely on the company culture - in the same way as dress code (or lack thereof), language and general behavior.

The only exception would be if you are a freelancer, where I as a client would expect an email related to your company and not a generic address at Gmail or Hotmail.

Having said that, I would be amazed if a candidate was rejected on their generic non-offensive email address alone.